# connect mqtt broker to web in the same server

Tags: php, security, websocket, mqtt, paho

I have a project where I have some raspberry pi connected to the broker via mqtt publishing and subscribing data, this broker is in a remote server.
I want to make a webpage where we can interact with the broker, publisging and subscribing, the web could be hosted in the same server too.

I was thinking about connect to the broker with the paho library, websockets and tls certicate. The web will be in php (laravel framework) with user authentification.
In concluision we will have to log in the site and have access to some topics.

My question is about security, javascript and websockets. As user will have access to the javascript code he will have access source code and also to the user and password we are using to connect to the server.

Will it be correct in terms of security? we will be using tls, web authentification and websockets.

I was considering to use php library to access to the topics instead of websockets but in that case all the load of the cennection will be in the server and I don't think that this is the correct way. Also I don't know how to keep a background php script running for the subscription while the web interface is running.

Will I have to do something more to improve the security?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hard code MQTT credentials into the javascript.

If you configure you broker to use a database to store it's credentials you can create temporary credentials that can be inserted into the database when the user logs into the webpage, you can then retrieve these credentials from the web server and use them to connect to the broker with the paho client.

You can then remove the credentials when the user logs off or the session expires.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that sounds a good idea, seems easy to implement,.Any plugin to use the database passwords?

Comment: Probably, but you've not said what broker you are using

Comment: My broker is Mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider two scenarios:

1. MQTT Broker is hidden from public internet and only the web server can access it.
2. MQTT Broker is exposed to the public internet and user agents are being sent credentials to operate it.

Note that 2 raises the attack surface a lot. You actually start to depend not only on proper configuration of the web server, but also of the MQTT Broker (double trouble). What if there are zero days? Do you want Shodan to know that you have a service there? You will be hacked before you know it.

In corporate reality the point 2 would be a no-go. If we could prevent MQTT Broker from being exposed, we would do that. In your project - you decide.

Comment: My iot devices are coneccted to the broker by the internet using tls1.2. What I was thinking about is to make a web app where the users have access to their devices(pub + sub). Would it be a problem? I don't really know if the scenario could be similar to the scenario 2  :(